# Top 50% not working, parent height is set to auto

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem trying to vertically center a child div inside its parent. I'm using this mixin:

```
@mixin vertical-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

But it seems that the "top: 50%" instruction is not working. I think that it may be because the parent div height is set to auto (it only has "min-height: 100%").

Any idea of how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried table property I use `display: table-cell;` in order to use `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the parent element has `position: relative` and change your code (the child element to be centered) to `position: absolute`. That should to the trick. Also take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) article on centering in CSS. Hope this helps!